# float a horizontal centered div

Tags: css, html

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate question, but I can't find an easy solution.

The Problem: I have a `div`displaying a timeline. This div is centered at the top by:

```css
margin: 0 auto
```

Now I have a search field, which should be displayed on the top right of the page. When the window is wide enought, both elements shoulb be displayed on the top.

If the window is too small, the timeline should float under the search field.

My Html:

```
<div class="search">
    <form.../>
</div>
<div class="timeline">...</div>
```

My Css:

```css
.search {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 14px;

    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
}

.timeline{
    width: 768px;
    height: 15px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 48px 40px 15px;
}
```

Comment: you need mediaquerie to check screen width and to switch from float to display , have you tried that ?

Comment: have a look at [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) to dynamically handle screen width behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mediaqueries like in this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/36PyU/8/)** :

add this CSS :

```
@media screen and (max-width:1000px) {
    .search {
        float:none;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
}
```